# How do I call a system function before registering users in Mongo RealmSwift?

Tags: swift, mongodb, realm

Apparently one of the requirements to call a Realm system function is to user login first. I need the user to confirm their external device ID to make sure it exists and is available. If it is, then proceed with emailPasswordAuth and user registration.

I've been triggering the if/elseif error handlers underneath `CheckDeviceAvailability` but somehow the `return` is ignored and the user is registered anyways. What am I doing wrong?

I've tried using `app.currentUser?.functions...`, and I've also tried nesting the function within the `app.login` block but something is still wrong. I don't really understand the `async` functionality so I imagine it has something to do with that.

```
func signUp(EMAIL: String, PASSWORD: String, CONFIRM: String, DEVICEID: String) {
        if EMAIL == "" || PASSWORD == "" || CONFIRM == "" || DEVICEID == "" {
            self.errorMSG = "Fields must be filled"
            return
        }
        
        if PASSWORD != CONFIRM {
            self.errorMSG = "Passwords must match"
            return
        }
        
        app.currentUser!.functions.CheckDeviceAvailability([AnyBSON(DEVICEID)]) { result, error in
            self.statusMSG = result?.stringValue
            if error != nil {
                self.errorMSG = "Failed to call function: \(error!.localizedDescription)"
                _ = app.currentUser?.logOut()
                return
                
            } else if result!.stringValue != "available" {
                self.errorMSG = "That device is already taken, try again"
                _ = app.currentUser?.logOut()
                return
                
            } else {
                
                app.emailPasswordAuth.registerUser(email: EMAIL, password: PASSWORD) { ERROR in
                    guard ERROR == nil else {
                        self.errorMSG = "Failed to register user: \(ERROR!.localizedDescription)"
                        return
                    }
                    
                    app.login(credentials: .emailPassword(email: EMAIL, password: PASSWORD)) { (RESULT) in
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            switch RESULT {
                            case .failure:
                                return
                            case .success(let USER):
                                        
                                let config = USER.configuration(partitionValue: "U-\(USER.id)")
                                Realm.asyncOpen(configuration: config) { (RES) in
                                    switch RES {
                                    case .failure(let ERR):
                                        self.errorMSG = "Failed to open realm: \(ERR)"
                                        return
                                    case .success(let REALM):
                                        self.statusMSG = "Open user realm success"
                                        let newUser = User()
                                        newUser._id = USER.id
                                        newUser.auraID = "U-\(USER.id)"
                                        newUser.Preferences = User_Preferences()
                                        newUser.Preferences?.email = EMAIL
                                        newUser.Preferences?.displayName = ""
                                        newUser.Preferences?.deviceID = DEVICEID
                                        newUser.Preferences?.signupDate = Date()
                                        
                                        try! REALM.write {
                                            REALM.create(User.self, value: newUser, update: .modified)
                                        }
                                        self.openUserRealm()
                                    }
                                    
                                }
                            
                                
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        
        }
```

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question ? Thanks

Comment: Doing some research on this right now. Seems like a solution to this would be to use an HTTP Endpoint. I'm currently not much familiar with this so I cannot provide an answer, but I'm leaving this for anyone in else in the future.